# Is that possible to make NginX respond just like the host is down?

Tags: nginx, tcp, disconnect

I have a website service on my server,
And I want the users to connect it only by domain and **not** by public ip. (*hiding the real ip*)

So I have tried make nginx respond like host is down when users access it via real ip, 
but it's just respond the status code, what I really want is make it respond to nothing.

I know that "`return 444`" can make ningx to drop disconnection, 
but it still doesn't respond like accessing a **non-existent host**.

---

##### This is what accessing an ip that doesn't exist looks like:

[image]

##### And this is what nginx return 444 looks like:

[image]

---

### Guess

I thought of a possibility, is it because of TCP's three-way handshake that it cannot hide itself?

- Non-existent host
  no response will be given when attempting to establish a TCP connection.
- Nginx "return 444"
  During TCP three-way handshake, the client sends SYN to the server, then the server responds with SYN, ACK, then the client requests HTML, the server drop connection, but the client still knows that the host already responded.

**If so, is there any workaround?**

Comment: For Nginx to respond only to a domain, the client must first negotiate a connection and pass the name of the domain to Nginx. So the server has already responded.

Comment: @Richard Smith - So it will not be possible to hide that nginx is being used with direct access to the public ip :(